# How to get the list of indices connecting two 1-d arrays?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, indices

Suppose A and B are two 1d arrays of different sizes such that *pythonically* B = A[C] where C is a particular list of indices meeting some specific but otherwise known condition. How to get C if A and B are both known? I tried `C = np.where(np.close(A, B))` but I get the following error message:

```
File "/home/username/../my_script.py", line 897, in get_histogram
    i0, i1 = np.where(np.isclose(hist_xs, vals1)), np.where(np.isclose(hist_ys, vals2))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in isclose
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 2260, in isclose
    return within_tol(x, y, atol, rtol)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 2246, in within_tol
    return less_equal(abs(x-y), atol + rtol * abs(y))
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (722,) (1536,)
```

In other words, I am trying to get only those elements of A whose right indices would correspond to the known B array.

Comment: Depends on the condition. If it is closeness the answer is different (simpler) than if it is some arbitrary condition.

Comment: A is the x coordinates of discretized 2d function (e.g. x values of 2d grids) while B is the x coordinates of some 2d random generator np.random.random(size=(sample_size, 2))

Comment: And the condition C basically wants to choose only those grid points that match the randomly generated 2d data points.

Comment: The function get_histogram() defines hist_valuess at (x,y) coordinates hist_xs and hist_ys. But I would like to know hist_valuess instead at some other points (x, y) coordinates vals1 and vals2. That's what I tried the above which I know is not right!

Comment: get_histogram() is defined as hist_valuess, hist_xs, hist_ys = np.histogram2d(....)

Comment: That all sounds a bit like what you ultimately want is some sort of interpolation? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?:

```
sorti = np.argsort(A)
C_inv = sorti[np.searchsorted(A,B,sorter=sorti)]
```

sample code (it works on any sortable array, if your array elements do not have comparison operator, you could write your own. If (less/greater) comparison is not applicable, you would need a for loop to find elements which seems to easy to include here):

```
A: [89 28 86 73 29 71 37 46 15 52]
B: [86 52 15]
C: [2 9 8]
C_inv: [2 9 8]
```